# Netherlands Renting Registration

Tags: netherlands, accommodation, rental

I am looking for a studio now in Utrecht, I saw posts with (registration allowed) and some not mentioned it. What is mean by Registration ? and what are its benefits? And Is it required for bank account ?

Comment: First search http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/local/official-matters/registration/registration

Comment: @Eugen Martynov thanks for your reply, but this is your registration to get BSN, what I am asking for that some accommodations ads mentioned this word (possible registration and some not), Why they mention it and how it will help me ?

Comment: http://www.access-nl.org/living-in-the-netherlands/moving/registering-with-your-local-municipality.aspx

Comment: http://www.expatica.com/nl/housing/Fair-rent-for-all-in-the-Netherlands_103709.html

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Amsterdam/comments/2r3ipd/how_do_people_register_when_theyre_living_in_a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means the rental is potentially legit.  Some people illegally sublet apartments, which means the intermediate remains registered at the address and will not permit the tenant to register.  If the tenant registers anyway, the authorities will realise a “collision” at the address and you will both run into trouble.  Subletting is a bad idea for many reasons, and this is one of them.  Do not sublet unless (1) the landlord permits it, and (2) the municipality permits it, or you know exactly what you are doing and you have no other choice.

I legally sublet my student apartment in The Netherlands in 2005 for six months.  I didn't inform the authorities I was living abroad, because the period was less than six months.  After I returned, the municipality contacted me because they had indications that I was no longer living at the address, but someone else was living there instead.  I replied and explained the situation, and it was OK, but it does show that the authorities *do* pay attention to this sort of thing.

Comment: That's mean If I want to make bank account, the apartment should be allowed to be registered to another person .. Continued to my main question, what about renting room in apartment, same situation and rules?

Comment: @AhmedRagheb I don't know in details what problems specifically as an immigrant you will experience if you can't register as living where you do.  My situation was domestically.  I imagine it's worse for a foreigner.